# SSH connection to ec2 Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I cannot SSH in to my ec2 instance from ubuntu 12.11.

I tried all the methods of ssh by giving key as credentials

I used

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ec2/pes.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-209-148-122.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

and I am getting the output as

```
OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-209-148-122.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.209.148.122] port 22.

debug1: connect to address 54.209.148.122 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-209-148-122.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Thank u,

Comment: Check for ssh service running on instance?

Comment: ssh is an essential tool for programmers, almost exclusively used by programmers (some net admins too)

Comment: Ensure that the security group associated with your instance allows incoming SSH traffic from your IP address. The default security group does not allow incoming SSH traffic by default. For more information https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Answer (score 11):

Please make sure that you have configured it on security group for **port 22**, you can refer it from the following link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: yes i configured secure group for port 22.. but still it was not working

Comment: Forgot to add the calling server to the whitelist.  That was it!

Comment: How/where did you add the calling server to the whitelist?

Comment: configured to port 22 and it was up immediately

Comment: From the AWS CLI, one can grant port 22 access for `my_ip` in `my_security_group_id` like so: `$ aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id <my_security_group_id> --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr <my_ip>/32`.

Answer (score 1):

Check for a firewall blocking access to this port or IP. It might be a firewall running on the client machine, the server machine or a network firewall running in the client network.