# Connection Time Out on Connection to EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

[image: DESC]    ssh ec2-user@13.52.253.252 -i Personal.pem

I connect using Windows comma[image]nd prompt with the above written command and get:

> ssh: connect to host 13.52.253.252 port 22: Connection timed out

When I attach the same EC2 host to default VPC it works find and I can connect. But when I connect it to the VPC I created ( With its two subnets and Internet Gateway  - See screenshot ) it doesnt connect as above.

I checked that most parameter of VPC and Subnets are same as default VPC.
What could be the reason it doesn't connect with VPC I created.

Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH connection to ec2 Connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739377/ssh-connection-to-ec2-connection-timed-out)

Comment: What are the security groups?

Comment: Check if security group allows for inbound traffic on port 22

Comment: Security Groups are there:  sgr-0c496c3464d0c5b2e 22 TCP 0.0.0.0/0 launch-wizard-7                                       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  I have added couple of pictures.